# sqlite not found on device

Tags: android, sqlite, device

I'm trying to connect to a Sqlite-DB. Testing on a device, I get a class-not-found-exception. I connect like so:

```
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + applicationPath + "data/appdata.db");
```

where the application path comes from the context and points to the data-folder. So far so good. The jar is in the build path and in the manifest,I have the following permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"  />
```

What am I missing? Any pointers appreciated!

Best regards,
Marcus

Comment: Did you install the driver jdbc for sqlite?
Did you import org.sqlite.JDBC?

Comment: if you want to connect to a local sqlite database on the device, that's not the way. read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: I import sqlitejdbc-v056.jar. I followed another tutorial, that worked well this way, didn't mention any driver installation, though?!

Comment: nice! make that an answer, so I can accept it. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some manufacturers deliver the devices without sqlite being installed on them. You can copy the sqlite program though from a emulator to your device if the device has an arm processor.

Start the emulator and use the adb command from the platform-tools in android-sdk

adb pull /system/xbin/sqlite3

Mount the system partition of your device read/write after this tutorial:

http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/01/mount-filesystem-read-write.html

Use the adb command to copy the sqlite3 file to your device

adb push sqlite3 /system/xbin/

After you reboot your device the sqlite3 command should work.

Comment: how to know whether that device have arm processor?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect to a local sqlite database on the device, that's not the way.

read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 0):

also check this: https://code.google.com/p/adb-sqlite-jdbc-driver/
but you should have installed the sqlite3 command already. you can, then, connect from your desktop to the sqlite db in your device